# How to hide the folder structure in php with bootstrap

Tags: .htaccess, directory-structure

I need to hide my admin folder here.

```
http://localhost/elc/admin/dashboard
```

I need it to display `http://localhost/elc/dashboard`

My folder structure is as follows:

```
htdocs
   -admin
      admin related files
   -user
      user-related files
   -.htaccess
   -index.php
```

This is the code I have written so far. If I do not include admin/dashboard the bootstrap template won't work.

```html
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^admin/dashboard$  /elc/admin/home.php [NC,L]

#Disabling Directory Browsing
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /elc/admin/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /elc/staff/404.php
```

I tried this as well.

```
RewriteRule dashboard$  /elc/admin/home.php [NC,L]
```

But, this does not display the bootstrap template. Pls, help!

Also, do I have to write RewriteRule ^admin/dashboard$  /elc/admin/home.php [NC,L] line for each and every link in the website?

Comment: Link `http://localhost/elc/admin/dashboard` should be served by home.php OR index.php?

Answer (score 0):

Please have your htaccess file in following manner. Make sure your htaccess is present inside root folder along with elc folder(not inside elc folder, besides it).

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on 

#Disabling Directory Browsing
Options -Indexes

##External redirect rule from http://localhost:80/elc/admin/dashboard ----> http://localhost:80/elc/dashboard Link here.    
RewriteRule ^(elc)/admin/(dashboard)/?$  /$1/$2? [R=301,L,NC]
##Internal rewrite rule to write on home.php file.
RewriteRule ^elc/dashboard/?$  elc/admin/home.php [NC,L]
    
ErrorDocument 404 /elc/admin/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /elc/staff/404.php
```

JS/CS rewrite/redirect: You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: @dilk, could you please do let me know if this answer has helped you?